# Hashicorp Vault ACLs

Tags: hashicorp-vault

In Vault documentation about [consul as backend storage](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage/consul.html), ACL is allowing write access to keys, services, nodes, agents and sessions. But what I need is more strict Consul ACL for Vault HA feature where Consul is used as HA-Backend.

Would in this case having only this ACL below be sufficient?

```
{
  "key": {
    "vault/": {
      "policy": "write"
    }
  },
  "service": {
    "vault": {
      "policy": "write"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!